# IPv6 address abbreviateion

Tags: ipv6

Given IPv6 address `2001:0000:0000:0000:1111:0000:0000:0000`, should it be abbreviated as: `2001::1111:0:0:0` or `2001:0:0:0:1111::`? It seems I didn't see any specification talking about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [RFC5952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5952.txt) - IPv6 Text Representation

```
4.2.3.  Choice in Placement of "::"

   When there is an alternative choice in the placement of a "::", the
   longest run of consecutive 16-bit 0 fields MUST be shortened (i.e.,
   the sequence with three consecutive zero fields is shortened in 2001:
   0:0:1:0:0:0:1).  When the length of the consecutive 16-bit 0 fields
   are equal (i.e., 2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1), the first sequence of zero
   bits MUST be shortened.  For example, 2001:db8::1:0:0:1 is correct
   representation.
```

In short: `2001::1111:0:0:0` is correct.

Comment: Well, both are correct, it's just that one notation is recommended :)  All the given notations work equally well

Comment: Well, that depends a little on how much you're interested in following the RFC 5952 standard. The `MUST` doesn't give you a choice when doing a proper implementation - as [RFC 2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) says about the use of keywords like MUSTin RFC documents ;)
All this doesn't mean that some device or software might not accept an incorrectly abbreviated address.

Comment: From the first paragraph of RFC 5952: "..., but all implementations must accept and be able to handle any legitimate RFC 4291 format.". The only addresses that are abbreviated incorrectly are those that don't follow RFC 4291. Everything that does must be accepted.

Comment: Agreed. Unless you claim your system/document/whatever being RFC 5952-compliant, this is just a recommendation ;)

Comment: @SanderSteffann, the way it was explained to me is that, yes, your implementation needs to accept any RFC 4291 format as input, but because RFC 5952 is a Standards Track RFC, you should only output addresses in RFC 5952 format.

Comment: @RonMaupin: I very much agree with that statement! :-)